# How can I inject a boolean of value true into a payload in Node-RED

Tags: iot, node-red

I have 3 sensors set up, I add a timestamp to each of these sensors and then I want to inject a boolean value into their payload.

I have successfully injected the boolean into the payload of my `sensordata`, but I cannot get the boolean to be `true` as it should be whenever the inject node is activated.

My code is below:

```
[{"id":"bca1865d.435e78","type":"websocket-listener","z":"","path":"/ws/iot","wholemsg":"false"},{"id":"981eb056.67e15","type":"ibmiot in","z":"c645a0e3.39ba6","authentication":"quickstart","apiKey":"","inputType":"evt","deviceId":"e197b6bd8a80","applicationId":"","deviceType":"+","eventType":"+","commandType":"","format":"json","name":"Sensor #1","service":"quickstart","allDevices":false,"allApplications":false,"allDeviceTypes":true,"allEvents":true,"allCommands":false,"allFormats":false,"x":220,"y":120,"wires":[["e4c932e3.1b36d","58a6047e.a759fc"]]},{"id":"e4c932e3.1b36d","type":"debug","z":"c645a0e3.39ba6","name":"Sensor data","active":false,"console":"false","complete":"true","x":482.5,"y":83,"wires":[]},{"id":"13ce88e9.ec3177","type":"websocket out","z":"c645a0e3.39ba6","name":"WebSocket","server":"bca1865d.435e78","client":"","x":903,"y":174,"wires":[]},{"id":"d0db918a.2f247","type":"cloudant out","z":"c645a0e3.39ba6","service":"gwens-iottrial2-cloudantNoSQLDB","cloudant":"","name":"","database":"iotsensortdata","payonly":true,"operation":"insert","x":912.5,"y":126,"wires":[]},{"id":"6979b2fb.96864c","type":"debug","z":"c645a0e3.39ba6","name":"Sensor JSON","active":false,"console":"false","complete":"true","x":913,"y":230,"wires":[]},{"id":"58a6047e.a759fc","type":"function","z":"c645a0e3.39ba6","name":"Add timestamp","func":"msg.topic = \"Sensor Data\";\nmsg.payload.time = Date.now();\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":483,"y":174,"wires":[["d24cfce6.fed3a"]]},{"id":"4c4be7e7.b3b418","type":"ibmiot in","z":"c645a0e3.39ba6","authentication":"quickstart","apiKey":"","inputType":"evt","deviceId":"64833708ebbf","applicationId":"","deviceType":"+","eventType":"+","commandType":"","format":"json","name":"Sensor #2","service":"quickstart","allDevices":false,"allApplications":false,"allDeviceTypes":true,"allEvents":true,"allCommands":false,"allFormats":false,"x":220,"y":174,"wires":[["58a6047e.a759fc"]]},{"id":"e5570623.1aa8f8","type":"ibmiot in","z":"c645a0e3.39ba6","authentication":"quickstart","apiKey":"","inputType":"evt","deviceId":"00933ded85c4","applicationId":"","deviceType":"+","eventType":"+","commandType":"","format":"json","name":"Sensor #3","service":"quickstart","allDevices":false,"allApplications":false,"allDeviceTypes":true,"allEvents":true,"allCommands":false,"allFormats":false,"x":221,"y":227,"wires":[["58a6047e.a759fc"]]},{"id":"fd41e3f7.d77f48","type":"inject","z":"c645a0e3.39ba6","name":"Occupancy","topic":"OccupancyBool","payload":"true","payloadType":"bool","repeat":"1","crontab":"","once":true,"x":485,"y":126.5,"wires":[["d24cfce6.fed3a"]]},{"id":"d24cfce6.fed3a","type":"function","z":"c645a0e3.39ba6","name":"Occupancy Injection","func":"var Occupancy = false;\n\nconsole.log(\"hi \" + msg);\n\nif(msg.topic == \"OccupancyBool\") {\n    if(msg.payload === true) {\n        Occupancy = true;\n    }\n}\n\nelse if(msg.topic == \"Sensor Data\") {\n    msg.payload.occupancy = Occupancy;\n    return msg;\n}\n/*\nswitch(msg.topic) {\n    case \"OccupancyBool\":\n        if(msg.payload === true) {\n            Occupancy = msg.payload;\n        }\n        console.log(\"occupancy bool\");\n        break;\n    case \"Sensor Data\":\n        msg.payload.occupancy = Occupancy;\n        console.log(\"sensor data\");\n        return msg;\n        break;\n    default:\n        console.log(\"default\");\n        break;\n}*/","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":691.5,"y":174.5,"wires":[["d0db918a.2f247","13ce88e9.ec3177","6979b2fb.96864c","76b1bbbe.8f57fc"]]},{"id":"76b1bbbe.8f57fc","type":"debug","z":"c645a0e3.39ba6","name":"","active":true,"console":"false","complete":"payload","x":844,"y":68,"wires":[]}]
```

How can I inject a boolean value of true into the payload of my sensor data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing the value of `Occupancy` in the `Occupancy Injection` function as a local variable. This means it is scoped to each individual invocation of the function. When the message from the Inject node comes it, it sets the value to true, then the function exist and the value is lost. When a sensor reading comes in, the value is reinitialised as false.

To store a value between invocations, you need to use the context object:

```
// Retrieve the last known value from context, default to false
var Occupancy = context.get('occupancy')||false;

if(msg.topic == "OccupancyBool") {
    if(msg.payload === true) {
        Occupancy = true;
    } else {
        Occupancy = false;
    }
    // store the value for next time
    context.set('occupancy',Occupancy);
}
```